# what is spring integration plugin for eclipse(luna) ? how it is done , what is STS ? , what is difference between these two

Tags: spring-integration

I found an answer for spring integration plugin as to add the "http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/ " by going to help in eclipse and go to install new software.  Is spring integration means that's it.

Answer (score 0):

STS is a preconfigured eclipse environment with the plugins installed as well as other goodies; see the [web site](https://spring.io/tools/sts) and [download page](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all).